# How to do a repeatable work with c# task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I use sharpPacp to receive udp packet, when the packed arrived , I use a BackgroundThread to process the received packed like this:

```
private void BackgroundThread()
{
    while (!BackgroundThreadStop)
    {
        bool shouldSleep = true;

        lock (QueueLock)
        {
            if (PacketQueue.Count != 0)
            {
                shouldSleep = false;
            }
        }

        if (shouldSleep)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
        else // should process the queue
        {
            //List<RawCapture> ourQueue;
            List<UdpPacket> ourQueue;
            lock (QueueLock)
            {
                // swap queues, giving the capture callback a new one
                ourQueue = PacketQueue;
                PacketQueue = new List<UdpPacket>();
            }

           //I write my repeatable work in here
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
           {
               ProcePacket(ourQueue);
           });

            if (statisticsUiNeedsUpdate)
            {
                UpdateCaptureStatistics();
                statisticsUiNeedsUpdate = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where  ProcePacket(ourQueue) is a methed take a long time to finished.
my program run for a while,then the cpu is almost 98% used and memory increased to a large number,at last it dead.
I think the problem is I create too many task ,but how can I do reapeatable work with only one task?

Comment: What ProcePacket do? Its execution takes too long as to be necessary to allocate a thread? Did you tried to perform this method of synchronous way to see how it comes out?

Comment: ProcePacket is used to take info from received packet and add to a List for show in the UI

Comment: Did you tried to perform this method of synchronous way to see how it comes out? If you are using WinForms don't forget use YourList.Invoke to add items in list. It will avoid Cross-thread operation not valid exception. See too: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If I perform this method of synchronous way,then ourQueue will not change,and the list will not change and the UI is the same

Comment: Use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` for long running tasks.